# Insert object into MongoDB object's array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to add an object into an empty array that is stored in one of my collections.

Currently this is how I have my collection setup:

```
[
  {
    "name": "user_added",
    "DRGs": []
  },
...
]
```

How can I insert an object into the collection so that it looks like this;

```
[
  {
    "name": "user_added",
    "DRGs": [ 
             {
              "code": "491",
              "name": "Back & neck procedures"
             }
    ]
  },
...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `$push` [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

You should be able to accomplish your goal with the following:

```
var collectionName = 'users'; // or whatever your actual collection name is
var objectToPush = {
   code: "491",
   name: "Back & neck procedures"
};

db.collection(collectionName).updateOne(
    {"name": "user_added"}, 
    { $push: { "DRGS": objectToPush }}
);
```